# Autokerasで得られたアーキテクチャを用いてCrossValidationを行いたい

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Autokerasで得られたアーキテクチャを使いクロスバリデーションを行いたいと考えているのですが、よい方法はございませんでしょうか。

下記2つ考えてみたのですが、良い方法がございましたらご教授いただけますと幸いです。

1. `from tensorflow.keras.models import clone_model`を使い保存したモデルをクローンして再度compileし、再度学習を行う。
   ⇛この方法ですと`clone`した情報にoptimizerやロス関数の情報が含まれないため、compile時にAutokerasで決定したハイパーパラメータで初期化する必要があるのですが、可能なのでしょうか。
2. 重みをリセットし再度学習する。[参考ページ](https://wak-tech.com/archives/1761)
   ⇛この方法ですと、optimizerの情報は保持されますが、おそらく学習後のoptimizerの状態で復元されますので、学習率やweight_decayなどが変動している可能性があるかと思います。

1の方法でoptimizerやロス含め復元できると良いか(保存済みモデルから取り出して何らかの方法で新しいオブジェクトにアタッチ?)と考えているのですが、方法はございますでしょうか。

よろしくおねがいいたします。